# Faster way on dealing with large Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have three 400k + rows Series named mask, replacement and id.
Mask is a  with all the indexes I want to carry operation on. For example if it is printed it looks like

```
Int64Index([76,114,154,207,209])
```

Replacement Series looks like this

```
76    2015-09-25
114   2016-02-15
154   2015-09-23
207   2015-10-20
209   2015-12-13
```

Id Series looks like this

```
76     A
114    B
154    C
207    D
209    E
```

And I have a dateframe, df_members that looks like this

```
     id   expire_date
0    A    2015-09-25
1    B    2016-01-15
2    C    2015-05-20
3    F    2017-02-28
4    G    2017-01-20
```

I would like to compare the id that exists in id Series, in this case id A,B,C and replace the expire_date with the dates in replacement Series if they don't match. In this case row with id B with 2016-02-15, row with id C with 2015-09-23. The problem is I can only think of using for loops. Which is not a feasible way. Any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `DataFrame` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by first and second `Series`, then create another Series for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and last replace by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
s = pd.concat([r, ID], axis=1, keys=('new_date','id')).set_index('id')['new_date']
print (s)
id
A    2015-09-25
B    2016-02-15
C    2015-09-23
D    2015-10-20
E    2015-12-13
Name: new_date, dtype: object

df['expire_date'] = df['id'].map(s).fillna(df['expire_date'])
#alternative
#df['expire_date'] = df['id'].map(s).combine_first(df['expire_date'])
print (df)
  id expire_date
0  A  2015-09-25
1  B  2016-02-15
2  C  2015-09-23
3  F  2017-02-28
4  G  2017-01-20
```